# How to connect ObjectBox to server instance?

Tags: java, objectbox, objectbox-java

I have a use-case wherein I have to connect objectbox from Java to server instance.

I tried with Sync but getting error stating "sync not supported". Below is my code,

```
BoxStore boxStore = MyObjectBox.builder().name("TestEntity-db").build();
Box<TestEntity> box = boxStore.boxFor(TestEntity.class);
boolean syncAvailable = Sync.isAvailable();
System.out.println("ObjectBox Sync is " + syncAvailable);         
SyncClient syncClient = Sync.client( boxStore, "ws://12.456.672.89:9999", SyncCredentials.none() ).buildAndStart();
```

Can someone help in this?

Comment: You need ObjectBox Sync for this. You can apply for it here: https://objectbox.io/sync/

Comment: @MarkusJunginger - If u could see the code which is attached above I have used Sync clinet to connect but getting an exception "This library does not include ObjectBox Sync Server. "Please visit https://objectbox.io/sync/ for options." from syncServerBuilder. I am using Java Spring Boot, not an android project. Can you help with this.

Comment: The shared code uses a client, not a server. Thus, it is expected that it will tell you that it does not include a server.

Comment: Hi @MarkusJunginger - Please find the below code which uses the sync server from Java Application , 

  BoxStore boxStore = MyObjectBox.builder().name("TestEntity-db").build();
  Box<TestEntity> box = boxStore.boxFor(TestEntity.class);  
boolean syncAvailable = Sync.isServerAvailable();
System.out.println("ObjectBox Sync is " + syncAvailable);    
 SyncServer syncServer = Sync.server(boxStore, "ws://12.456.672.89:9999",
 SyncCredentials.none()).buildAndStart();

Getting error , "This library does not include ObjectBox Sync Server. Please visit https://objectbox.io/sync/ for options."

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the intended setup. Do you actually want an embedded ObjectBox Sync server running in your process? Maybe a Sync client connecting to an existing Sync Server could be an option too? I realized we are in touch outside of stackoverflow already; let's continue there?

Comment: Yes Sure @MarkusJunginger will continue there